# VS style snippets in SSMS 2012. Do they exist?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssms, code-snippets, ssms-2012

I am trying to setup a simple snippet in SQL Server management studio.  When I heard the word "snippet", I assume that they would work like they do in Visual Studio.  By that I mean that there are variables that get filled in, etc...  I am not seeing that.

Can someone tell me whether SSMS 2012 supports Visual Studio style snippets.  If so, can you provide an example of a snippet that supports variable replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be close to what your looking for.  Under View->Template explorer is a list of a whole bunch of structures that you regularly use when working with, building, developing databases.  You can also get to it using `Ctrl+Alt+T`.  There are literally hundreds in there.  Everything from building a view to setting up a trigger to creating XML schemas.

The really nice thing with templates is you can build your own structures that you regularly use.  I have built quite of few of my own templates to hold snippets that I have acquired from the likes of [Brent Ozars blitz scripts](http://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) and others like [the improved SP_WHO from Adam Machanic](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2007/12/31/a-gift-of-script-for-2008-who-s-active-what-are-they-doing-and-who-is-blocked.aspx) and such.

While maybe not as fancy (read interactive) as the ones you'll find in the Visual Studio projects I find them very handy.

If you use these templates there is another little feature that can be very handy.  If you press **`Ctrl-Shift-M`** (or use the toolbar button that shows an A->B) you get a dialog that lets you easily replace the template parameters with your own values.

---

Update post research into SSMS2012

I just recently started using SSMS 2012 and see there is a new feature that I wasn't aware of.  When right clicking you do in fact see the 'Insert Snippet' drop down.  I understand your question better now.  Apparently however, these are pretty much the same as what I posted above.